# Vue 3 nested routes

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router4

Given the following route:

```
{
path: '/detail/:someId',
component: SomeDetailComponent,
name: 'some-detail',
children: [
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    name: 'dashboard'
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirect: { name: 'dashboard' }
  },
  {
    path: 'other',
    component: OtherComponent,
    name: 'other'
  }
]
```

},

Why does this work (the dashboard component is visible):

```
this.$router.push(`/detail/123/`);
```

But this doesn't:

```
this.$router.push({name: 'some-detail', params: { someId: 123 }});
```

In one case, the URL gets a trailing slash while in the other it doesn't. I've read somewhere in the docs that this is a breaking change coming from Vue2. See:
[named-children-routes-with-an-empty-path-no-longer-appends-a-slash](https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/migration/index.html#named-children-routes-with-an-empty-path-no-longer-appends-a-slash)

So the real question here could be: how can I still have my working child navigations (with redirection) while still being able to navigate using the route name, instead of the route url part.

Comment: The name is `some-detail` but in the push you use `detail`, is that a copy paste problem or the actual issue?

Comment: Damn, this was a copy paste problem, thx for pointing out, I've edited my question.